# Dynamically created image button click event is not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net

On dynamically created table based on some condition i've added imagebutton dynamically. parallelly i want to add event for this image button click but the click event is not getting fired. here is my code snippet.

```
    private void createTable()
    {
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
        TableCell ImageCell = new TableCell();
        ImageButton imgBtndeleteAttr = new ImageButton();
        imgBtndeleteAttr.ID = "imgbtn_" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
        imgBtndeleteAttr.CssClass = "deleteDynamic";
        imgBtndeleteAttr.OnClientClick = "javascript:return confirm('Do you want to delete this Attribute?');";
        imgBtndeleteAttr.Click += new System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventHandler(imgBtndeleteAttr_Click);
        ImageCell.Controls.Add(imgBtndeleteAttr);
        tableRow.Cells.Add(ImageCell);
    }
```

and here is the event

```
    protected void imgBtndeleteAttr_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {

        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "lnk",
           "<script type = 'text/javascript'>alert('Image button Clicked');</script>");
    }
```

Comment: Do you call `createTable()` on the `Page.IsPostBack`?  All dynamically created controls must be **recreated** on the post-back, otherwise they don't exist and the event handler isn't created

Comment: no. i cant call the createTable() on the Page.IsPostBack or page load becouse the table and controlls want to generate based on user select parameter

Comment: If there will only ever be **one single** dynamic item, then just create it normally and set `Visible="false"` in the markup - then you can change it in the code to `.Visible = true;` when required.  If there are multiple, then you're in a world of pain that I don't have time to explain

Answer (score 1):

Its a bad idea to use dynamic controls in asp. The controls have to be recreated on postback. So if you create a button dynamically and click it, postback happens and event is triggered but due to postback the button which triggered the event is destroyed and the raised event is discarded.

Comment: Then may i know how to handle this type of process in asp.net. if we want to create and implement some dynamic control means what is the best way to achieve it

Comment: there is no clean way to handle this. you will have to create the control before hand and set  Visible=false. else if the condition to create the buttons is data driven i would use a datalist

Comment: In my case data driven is not possible. also the datalist too. i cant hide the controlls in pageload. becouse it should generate based on user input. if there is any other way to do this.?

Comment: You can create a datatable with one column and 1 row. put any value into it . then bind it with datalist which contains the button. your button is created and you can make it do what ever you want. This is what i actually did to create a dynamic button